# Completeness of the metric r(x,y)=min{d(x,y},1}

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Can somebody help me out with the following:

If (X,d) is a metric space and r(x,y)=min{d(x,y},1} for all x,y in X. 
I proved that r is a metric and that r and d are equivalent.
Now I want to prove that (X,r) is complete if and only if (X,d) is complete.

This was my idea: Suppose {xn} is a Cauchy sequence in X, then {xn} is r-convergent in X (completeness). Because of the equivalence of r and d, {xn} is also d-convergent and thus (X,d) is complete. The other way is the same.
Can somebody say if this is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your idea doesn't quite work. Topological equivalence is agnostic to distances, which are used to define the notion of a Cauchy sequence. For example, we can endow $\Bbb{R\setminus Q}$ with a complete metric which is equivalent to the standard metric, which is far from being complete.

**HINT:** Recall that in the definition of a Cauchy sequence we care more about small $\varepsilon$ than about large $\varepsilon$.

In particular, what happens when we consider $\varepsilon<1$? How do the metrics $r$ and $d$ differ in that case?

Comment: OP is right though: equivalence preserves completeness so for this particular example, the explicit definition of $r$ is not really that important.

Comment: The OP didn't specify whether or not this is topological equivalence (in which case your comment, and the approach by the OP are wrong, e.g. $\Bbb R$ is equivalent with $(0,1)$ both in their standard metrics); or strong equivalence in the sense that the metrics bound one another (in which case, yes, it is correct). Since I left my mind reading cap in my office, I went with what came into mind first, which happened to be the former notion of equivalence.

Comment: It's topological equivalence

Comment: @Roos: In which case, the strategy you provide is insufficient. It is possible to endow the irrational numbers (and the standard metric) with a topologically equivalent metric which is complete; but certainly the standard metric is far from being complete.

Comment: @fuglede: So it turns out that the definition of $r$ is very important.

Comment: Ok, but how do I have to prove it?

Comment: @Roos: Try to think how to use the hint I gave.

Comment: Then r and d are the same?

Comment: @RoosJansen: For small distances, yes. For large distances, not necessarily.

Comment: My definition of equivalence: for every sequence (xn) in X and x in X yields: d(x,xn)->0 if and only if r(x,xn)->0

Comment: @ Roos Jansen: Your definition of equivalence is true only in metric spaces not in topological spaces in general. For example there exist two topological spaces with the same convergent sequences while their topologies differ.( i.e., they dont have same open sets)

Comment: But in my case of equivalence my proof is correct?

Comment: @Roos: Yes, if the equivalence is in the convergence of *all* sequences, then yes. But that's not topological equivalence, as been noted several times by now.